# How to route Web API with multiple parameters?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

How to route Web API with multiple parameters, like StackOverflow does, with Self Host Asp.NET?

**Stackoverflow API in question:**

/questions/**{ids}**/answers - Get the answers to the questions identified by a set of ids.

/questions/**{id}**/close/options -Returns valid flag options which are also close reasons for the given

As you see you can call /questions with one ID or with IDs
How should I route to achieve this?

**Requirements**

/questions/**{id or ids}**/answers

/questions/**{id or ids}**/answers/redo

/questions/**4,5,7** => should bring questions with those ids

/questions/**4,5,7**/answers => should bring answer to those questions.

**Edit:**

Sample query => /2.2/questions/**{ids}**/comments?**order=asc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow**

Comment: This kind of screams Odata.  I don't have much experience with Odata, but I know one of the things you can do with Odata is specify via the URL a query.  Such as your requirement of only needing answers for a collection of questions.  So make a query via Odata that returned the questions you need answers to.  Here's an example of what an URL could look like with Odata:

http://localhost:8080/owind.svc/Categories?$orderby=CategoryName desc&$top=4

Please see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-$select,-$expand,-and-$value for more information.

Comment: if you look at there 
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-questions you can see query comes after the api structure
/2.2/questions/{ids}/comments?order=asc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow